# RSA Encryption message Length

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, modulus

So i know that to encrypt a message in RSA we use cipher = m^e % n where m is the plain text transformed to an integer of size {0,..,n -1} and n is the modulus.
Let's say that the size of n is 8192bit and e = 65537 and m (as an integer) = n - 4.
So the question is wouldn't be (2^(8192-4))^65537 impossible to calculate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not impossible at all - the exponentiation is performed modulo `n`, which means that the result will always be less than `n`. This not only limits the output size, but makes the calculation easier as intermediate stages can be reduced modulo `n` to keep the numbers involved "small". The Wikipedia page on [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) provides more detail on how the calculation can be performed.